# ValueError when reading arff file with binary content in python

Tags: python, binary, valueerror, arff

code as follows:

```
data = arff.loadarff('Training Dataset.arff')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[0])
df.head()
```

Error:
ValueError: -1 value not in (' -1', '1 ')

new to python.. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.